# XAML GridLength resource with value bound to another resource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to define a GridLength as XAML resources in a ResourceDictionary setting the length value using another StaticResource?

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
<System:Double x:Key="MyValue">8</System:Double>
<Thickness x:Key="MyThickness"
           Bottom="{StaticResource MyValue}"
           Left="{StaticResource MyValue}"
           Right="{StaticResource MyValue}"
           Top="{StaticResource MyValue}" />
<GridLength x:Key="MyGridLength">{StaticResource MyValue}</GridLength>
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that exactly like you want to. If you pass any string inside  - it will be passed to GridLengthConverter directly and not parsed (so StaticResource etc are ignored). If you will pass xml inside  it will be interpreted as content, and GridLength does not support direct content.

So most reasonable option is just duplicate "8" and put MyGridLength near MyValue. Otherwise - move both to static properties (but there you will have only one field with value of 8, so no duplication) and reference via {x:Static}